# Can't get id of module in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I try to get id of module by position in templates/mytemplate/index.php (Joomla 3.3.3) and use the code:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('top');
echo $module->id;
```

but I get nothing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `JModuleHelper::getModule`, you are only allowed to define the name or type of the module. You cannot define the position. So instead, type in the name, for example:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('login');

echo $module->id;
```

If you still want to get the module by position, then you must use `JModuleHelper::getModules`. Note the `s` at the end.

### Update:

As the second option will give you an array of multiple modules that belong to that position, you will need to use the following which will give you the first instance of the array:

```
echo $modules[0]->id;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, it also doesn't work. The module is published, the position is only one and I get the array: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 100 [title] => ... successfully if I use print_r($module) but cann't get id if use $module->id Maybe something was changed in API in Jooomla 3.3.3 ?

Comment: Thanks, this works! One more question: how can I get the parameter "note"? I try $modules[0]->note but it doesn'work and I see there is no this parameter in array